# Database of Supabase UPDATE doesn't work on Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, supabase

I had a problem with Database of Supabase on Flutter.
I couldn't **update** the database.
I implemented the sign in feature with Google.

And I referenced this video: [Flutter Database & User Authentication Quickstart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r7ysVtZ5Row&t=0s)

What should I do?

My code is

```sql
final userId = supabase.auth.currentUser!.id;
final username = _nameController.text.trim();

await supabase.from('profiles').update({
     'username': username,
     // the list has place name
     'places': userPlacesList,
}).eq('id', userId);
                            
}
```

My sql code is

```
create table profiles (
  id uuid references auth.users not null primary key,
  updated_at timestamp with time zone,
  username text unique,
  avatar_url text,
  places text[],

  constraint username_length check (char_length(username) >= 1)
);

alter table profiles
  enable row level security;

create policy "Public profiles are viewable by everyone." on profiles
  for select using (true);

create policy "Users can insert their own profile." on profiles
  for insert with check (auth.uid() = id);

create policy "Users can update own profile." on profiles
  for update using (auth.uid() = id);


create function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger as $$
begin
  insert into public.profiles (id, username, avatar_url)
  values (new.id, new.raw_user_meta_data->>'username', new.raw_user_meta_data->>'avatar_url');
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

These are photos;

- My Table

[table-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNKZH.png)

[table-photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xanB.png)

- My policies

[all-policies-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgtGg.png)

[viewable-policy-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX42i.png)

[insert-policy-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2BZf.png)

[update-policy-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib9Cn.png)

Please help me...

**What did I do:**
I changed the Target roles of **"Users can update own profile."** from Default to authenticated.
But nothing happened.
I think that creating function was bad for me. I don't know it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself.
I changed my code:

```dart
final userId = supabase.auth.currentUser!.id;
final username = _nameController.text.trim();

await supabase.from('profiles').upsert({
      'id': userId,
      'username': username,
      'places': userPlacesList,
});
```

I thought update function can make the data on database when the data isn't there.
But I noticed that if I don't have the data on database, update function won't add it.
So I changed to upsert from update.

Thank you for reading!